# Lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar strange error

Tags: lightbox

i have a crazy issue with the lightbox plugin by lokesh dhakar.
On my Homepage in the footer right before i include the lightbox.js there appears a lightbox but its really weird.

Link to the page: http://www.teuschl.co.at

Comment: Can you add more specifics about your problem. Thanks.

Comment: just navigation to the linked page - there in the footer is a lightbox, but i dont know why ..

Comment: You are using Lightbox v2.7.1. In main.js you are using the option method on the `lightbox` object to set resizeDuration and maxWidth. The option method was introduced after v2.7.1. Please grab the latest version of the scrip (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and see if that changes the behavior. The lightbox div should be hidden in the build method. Unclear why it isn't happening on your site. `this.$lightbox.hide()...`

Comment: Hello Lokesh Dhakar,
i still have this issue, i updated the js and css .. maybe another hint from you?

Comment: u just added to style.css .lightbox {display:none;} it seems to work